# C++ DirectX11 Returning an Enum class

Tags: c++, enums

Header File:

```
protected:
enum class GameState
    {
        nullState
        , firstState
        , secondState
    };

GameState gameState;
```

in the CPP file I want to return the state that gameState is currently at, how do I do this as enum is not a type?

I tried doing:

```
int ReturnGameState()
{
    return this->gameState;
}
```

because I thought the enums were stored as ints but it says the return types are different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can.  Why do you have "class" in your enum declaration?  That is not correct syntax.  The code below compiles just fine.

```
enum  GameState
    {
        nullState
        , firstState
        , secondState
    };

GameState ReturnGameState()
{
    GameState r = firstState; //example
    return r;
}
```